# Problem statement-Unable to understand wording of the problem

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I was trying to code to improve my coding skills.I got a problem but I am not sure what the problem statement is.Can someone help in understanding the problem.I will code accordingly.
Fleet of Drones

**Problem statement**

You’re given a fleet of drones.

The drones are lined up and represented by the characters > and <. > indicates that the drone is pointing forward and < indicates that the drone is pointing backward. An operator is control of the fleet can perform several operations. An operation makes use of a start position index and an end position index and it re-orients all the drones which fall between the indexes (and including the indexes themselves). The objective is to output the final state of the drones.

Input Format

The first line of input consists of an integer t denoting the number of test cases. The first line of each test case consists of an integer n denoting the number of drones. The second line is the orientation representation of n drones. Third line consists of an integer o denoting the number of operations. Next o lines follow each consisting of two space separated integers s (denoting the start index) and e (denoting the end index). Index starts from 0.

**Sample Input**

```
3
4
<<<<
1
0 2
2
<>
0
5
'><<<<'
5
0 2
1 2
0 2
0 4
3 3
```

Sample output:

```
'>>><'
<>
<<><>
```

Comment: flip characters '<' and '>' within a given array, based on pairs of `[start, end]` indices.

Comment: @Michael -I understand but I was not getting the problem statement.@Jeremy -Thanks

Comment: What exact part don't you understand?  Please highlight this in your question.

Comment: Third input gives incorrect output as per my understanding and my code.I mean if I have to perform the function 5 times on input one by one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split it down and go through it bit by bit and read the instructions thoroughly to ensure you understand.  I have taken each line and stated what it is and the results of each operation for each test case below.

```
3       = Number of Test Cases

== Test case 1 ==
4       = Number of drones
<<<<    = Start orientation of each drone (4 as per line above)
1       = Number of operations

== Operation 1 of Test case 1 ==
0 2     = Start & end index 


== Result of Test case 1 ==

>>><

== Test case 2 ==
2       = Number of drones
<>      = Start orientation of each drone
0       = Number of operations


== Result of Test case 2 ==

<>

== Test case 3 ==
5       = Number of drones
><<<<   = Start orientation of each drone 
5       = Number of operations

== Operation 1 of Test case 3 ==
0 2     = Start & end index 

== Operation 2 of Test case 3 ==
1 2     = Start & end index 

== Operation 3 of Test case 3 ==
0 2     = Start & end index 

== Operation 4 of Test case 3 ==
0 4     = Start & end index 

== Operation 5 of Test case 3 ==
3 3     = Start & end index 


== Result of Test case 2 ==

<>><<   = after operation 1
<<<<<   = after operation 2
>><<<   = after operation 3
<<>>>   = after operation 4
<<><>   = after operation 5 (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter number of  Test cases");
            int testcases = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for(int k=1;k<=testcases;k++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number of drones for {0} test case",k);
                int numofdrones = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("enter the orientaion for {0} drones as < or > ", numofdrones);
                string dronesOrientaion = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter number of operation required for {0} test case", k);
                int numOperation = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Dictionary<int, List<int>> indexofoperation = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= numOperation; i++)
                {
                    List < int > indexval= new List<int>();
                    Console.WriteLine("enter start index");
                    int startindex = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    indexval.Add(startindex);
                    Console.WriteLine("enter end index");
                    int endindex = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    indexval.Add(endindex);
                    indexofoperation.Add(i, indexval);
                }


                finalDroneState(dronesOrientaion, indexofoperation);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void finalDroneState(string dronesOrientaion, Dictionary<int, List<int>> indexofoperation)
        {
            string initialString = dronesOrientaion;
            foreach (var item in indexofoperation)
            {
                //for (int a = 0; a < item.Key; a++)
                //{
                    List<int> operationval = item.Value;
                    int[] arr1 = operationval.ToArray();

                    for (int s=arr1[0];s<=arr1[arr1.Length-1];s++)//each (int m in operationval)
                    {

                        char[] ch = initialString.ToCharArray();
                        if (ch[s] == '>')
                        {
                            ch[s] = '<';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ch[s] = '>';
                        }
                        initialString = new string(ch);
                    }
               // }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(initialString);

        }

    }
}
```